# Converting repeating decimals to fractions in java

Tags: java, double, decimal, calculator, fractions

I am new to Java and am making a fractional calculator.

Basically I convert the fractions to decimals(double), add/subtract/multiply/divide them, round them to two decimal places, then convert them back to fractions in simplest form.

It works until I run into repeating decimals. I assume the problem is with the inaccuracy of double and the rounding to two decimal places, but I don't know how to resolve such a problem without completely redoing the entire code.

**For Example:** 5/2 + 7/3 = 29/6 , *but it ends up at 483/100*

So how would I be able to make such an expression equal **29/6** rather than **483/100**.

It works fine for an expression such as 5/10 + 1/2 = 1/1

Comment: Your example is wrong. 5/2+7/3 should be ~483/100

Comment: By going to `double`, and truncating to 2 decimal places, you're loosing all precision; that cannot lead to a correct result. Why not perform the operations directly on the numerator and denominator of both fractions?

Comment: Don't  convert between fractions and doubles.  Make a `Fraction` class that stores the numerator and the denominator as separate numbers.

Comment: The fact that `double` is a binary fraction type, not a decimal type, only makes the proposed plan worse. I strongly agree with writing a rational number package or using an existing one.

Comment: The `5/10 + 1/2 = 1/1` case has the unusual property that every value in it is exactly representable as a `double`.

Comment: 29/6 is approximately equal to 483/100. How are you converting back to fractions? I think your code would run into this problem with x/3, x/6, x/7, and x/9. If this is homework, I would redo it all there's too many cases where the code works as opposed to where it does not.

Comment: Instead of converting to decimal, directly add the two fractions as we do it by hand using this formula : **denominator = deno_1 * deno_2** and **numerator = nume_1 * deno_2 + nume_2 + deno_1**. After that, simplify the fraction.